# JavaScript & HTML: Event Listener Is Not Producing Text Alert As Expected; ReferenceError: button is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, dom, alert, addeventlistener

I am trying to implement an Event Listener on a DOM (webpage) that produces an alert when a user submits an input inside an input box.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DOM Examples</title>
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"></link>  -->

</head>


<body>

    <h1 id="title">This is my Title </h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder="some text">
    <button id='submit-text-btn'>Submit</button>

    <p>
        This is the text that is going to display. 
        I really need to figure out how to balance the next week out. 
        Maybe just pour myself into this and finish recursion, classes, plus guessing game quickly. 
    </p>


    <script src="dom.js"></script>


</body>


</html>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
function getInputAndUpdate(inputElement){
    const text = inputElement.value;
    inputElement.value = '';
    alert(text);
}

button.addEventListener('click', function(){

    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input');

    getInputAndUpdate(inputElement); 

});
```

Below is a screen shot of my resulting webpage:

[image]

My problem is nothing happens when I type text into the input box and click submit.  No Alert message pops up at all.

Below is the error I see in the console:

```
dom.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: button is not defined
```

[image]

Comment: Well you have neither declared nor initialized the variable `button`.

Comment: apologies, I'm quite new to this.  Where / how would I declare it in my example?

Comment: You should declare the `button` variable before it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `button` variable you're adding the event listener on hasn't been initialised.

To get a reference of an element in the DOM, use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) (which retrieves the element that has the ID - note that IDs must be unique), [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (which retrieves all elements that have the class) or [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) (which retrieves all elements by their tag name).

In this case, since you're already using an ID on the button, you can retrieve the element with `document.getElementById`:

```js
function getInputAndUpdate(inputElement){
    const text = inputElement.value;
    inputElement.value = '';
    alert(text);
}

var button = document.getElementById('submit-text-btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){

    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input');

    getInputAndUpdate(inputElement); 

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DOM Examples</title>
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"></link>  -->

</head>


<body>

    <h1 id="title">This is my Title </h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder="some text">
    <button id='submit-text-btn'>Submit</button>

    <p>
        This is the text that is going to display. 
        I really need to figure out how to balance the next week out. 
        Maybe just pour myself into this and finish recursion, classes, plus guessing game quickly. 
    </p>


    <script src="dom.js"></script>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select your button like this

```
const button = document.getElementById("submit-text-btn");
```